# zend framework project uploaded to sub domain not working

Tags: apache, zend-framework, .htaccess

I uploaded as website to a subdomain, and every page is not working except the front page 
please check it [here](http://websmartus.com/demo/globaltours/public_html/). What could be the possible reason?

I should have 8 pages in front level and many more on admin level but I am getting 404 error as you can see.

UPDATE:: .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

UPDATE to url routing

I do have few url router like below BUT I don't have any default router

```
    $router->addRoute(
        'get-destination',
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('destination/get/:id/:dest-name', array(               
            'controller'    => 'destination',
            'action'        => 'get',
            'id'            => 'id',
            'dest-name'         => 'dest-name'
        ))
    );
```

just to make look cooler and on my navigation (which is loaded from xml I have) something like

```
 <nav>
    <home>
        <label>HOME</label>
        <controller>index</controller>
        <action>index</action>
        <route>default</route>
    </home>
```

since I was getting url problem from where url was routed

and please check phpinfo at http://websmartus.com/demo/globaltours/public_html/phpinfo.php

Comment: My guess would be rewrite rules in .htaccess. Have a search about zend framework and shared hosting.

Comment: @Marcin i have somewhat similar project http://demo.websmart.com.np/globaltours/public/ but its working

Comment: @explorex. Not sure whether this is the same. In the first case you have one folder more (i.e. demo). Also in the first case you have public_html whereas in the second you have public. But these are just my guesses.

Comment: @Marcin it's same its inside demo folder http://websmartus.com/demo/globaltours/public_html/

Comment: @explorex. I meant that at demo.websmart.com.np/globaltours/public you don't have this /demo/ folder. Your project is in the root, i.e. demo.websmart.com.np. In http://websmartus.com/demo/globaltours/public_html/ your project is not in the root, but in /demo/ folder.

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess file?

Comment: @Marcin no its same please check http://websmart.com.np/demo/globaltours/public/index.php it's same. if you have got any suggestions then i would appreciate a lot. i worked so hard on this project and now it does not work. My boss is going to get very angry

Comment: I don't think this is the answer, but the last two lines of your .htaccess file are redundant. The 'L' flag on the first RewriteRule directive stands for "Last," and should mean that the second one will never be executed.

Comment: @gravelpot anyway thanks for your effort, i will try to upload once, if it works i will let you know

Comment: I also think that there is something else different about the way your two example sites are configured, since I assume you are using the url() view helper on both, but the URLs it is emitting have the "index" controller name at the end on the site that is working, but not on the site that is not working. Do you have a default route configured on the site that is not working?

Comment: @explorex. Try setting baseUrl in application.ini as follows: resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/demo/globaltours/public_html"

Comment: @Marcin tha'sts not working  please check http://demo.websmartus.com/globaltours/public_html/test.php it contains the filepath of index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon the problem is in .htaccess. It should be looking like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /demo/globaltours/public_html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: no .. the problem originated due to different root for apache and php. please check error from the page (clicking or any nav button) and and this onehttp://websmartus.com/demo/globaltours/public_html/test.php which contains the directory index.php. i dont know how to fix this if you do then please update your answer

Comment: Are you sure your .htaccess is actually working? Maybe it is not being executed by Apache.